# Error: El buzón de correo no esta disponible. La respuesta del servidor fue 5.3.4

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Al tratar de enviar un correo en una página ASP.NET, me lanza el error que describí en el título:

```
Dim mensaje As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
'Direccion de correo a la cual enviaremos el mensaje
mensaje.To.Add("correo@outlook.es")
'Asunto
mensaje.Subject = TextBox1.Text
mensaje.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
'Cuerpo del mensaje
Dim body As String = String.Format("Mensaje: {0}  De: {1}", TextBox3.Text, TextBox2.Text)
mensaje.Body = body
mensaje.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
mensaje.IsBodyHtml = True 'Si queremos que se envíe como HTML
'Correo desde el cual enviaremos el mensaje
mensaje.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(TextBox2.Text)
'-----CLIENTE DE CORREO-----'
'creamos un objeto del cliente de correo
Dim cliente As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
'se crean las credenciales del correo emisor
cliente.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("correo2@outlook.es", "password")
'configuramos el puerto y la seguridad
cliente.Port = 25
cliente.EnableSsl = True
cliente.Host = "smtp.live.com"

'-----ENVIO DEL CORREO-----'
Try
    cliente.Send(mensaje)
    Response.Write("<script>alert('Tu mensaje fue enviado satisfactoriamente')</script>")
Catch ex As System.Net.Mail.SmtpException
    Response.Write(String.Format("<script>alert('{0}')</script>", ex.Message))
End Try
```

¿Podrían ayudarme a solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que el problema es el puerto que usas

[Outlook.com POP3 and SMTP Settings for Microsoft Outlook](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/outlook.com-settings-pop3-smtp-imap/)

Intenta usando el puerto `587`

---

Tambien podrias usar

SMTP: smtp-mail.outlook.com

puerto: 587

[Configurar una aplicación de correo electrónico con Outlook.com](http://windows.microsoft.com/es-AR/windows/outlook/send-receive-from-app)

---

[MailMessage - Envia mail con GMail (1/3)](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2012/07/mailmessage-envia-mail-con-gmail-13.html)

Sino podrias usar un smtp diferente como ser el de Gmail para probar que el codigo funciona.

Comment: Lo intente de esa manera pero me sigue mandando el mismo error, hay que modificar lo siguiente: <mailSettings>
            <smtp from="">
                <network defaultCredentials="false" host="" password="" userName="" />
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>

Comment: si defines la configuracion en el app.config entonces si, pero en tu caso lo estas asignando desde codigo. Edite la respuesta, valida si usando otro smtp funciona el codigo

Comment: Es correcto, probe con el smtp de google y funciono de manera correcta

Comment: entonces es un tema con la configuracion del smtp de outlook, quizas sea el puerto o no esta resolviendo correctamente

Comment: edite la respuesta, intenta con el smtp que agregue

Comment: @GuillermoRicardo, si esta respuesta ayudó a solucionar el problema de tu pregunta, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) haciendo click en el **✔️**, que está bajo las flechas de votación, a la izquierda de la misma.

Answer (score 0):

El error 5.3.4 indica que el correo ha sido rechazado por las políticas anti-spam de outlook.

Puede ser que te dé el error por utilizar como from un email diferente al que utilizas en las credenciales o porque has excedido un número de correos enviados establecido por el servidor (generalmente suele ser un límite diario).

Por lo demás el código es correcto.